# Why is Log4j2 JsonLayout + KeyValuePair printing empty logEvent messages

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j2, slf4j, tomcat-juli

**TL;DR**
If I'm using JsonLayout with a nested KeyValuePair in my log4j2.xml config the resulting log messages are empty. Any ideas why?

**Long Story**

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.43 with the following logging related JARs:

- jackson-annotations-2.9.7.jar
- jackson-core-2.9.7.jar
- jackson-databind-2.9.7.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
- jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
- log4j-api-2.12.0.jar
- log4j-core-2.12.0.jar
- log4j-jul-2.12.0.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.0.jar
- tomcat-extras-juli-8.5.2.jar (as tomcat-juli.jar in /bin)
- tomcat-extras-juli-adapters-8.5.2.jar
- log4j-web-2.12.0.jar (in the webapp)

and the log4j2.xml config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
  <Console name="consoleappender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <JsonLayout compact="true" eventEol="true" stacktraceAsString="true" locationInfo="true">
      <KeyValuePair key="foo" value="bar"/>
    </JsonLayout>
  </Console>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="consoleappender" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

In the setenv.sh I set the classpath to:

```
CLASSPATH="$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar\
:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-api.jar\
:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-core.jar\
:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/log4j-jul.jar\
:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/jackson-annotations.jar\
:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/jackson-core.jar\
:$CATALINA_HOME/lib/jackson-databind.jar"
```

And run Tomcat with the additional JVM args:

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:log4j2.xml"
```

So every Tomcat, JULI, Apache commons and Slf4j logging should be redirected to Log4J2 in the end.

Unfortunately all I see is this: `{"logEvent":"","foo":"bar"}`

Instead of something like this:
`{"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener","message":"Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.43","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.ApiLogger","threadId":1,"source":{"class":"org.apache.juli.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger","method":"log","file":"Jdk14Logger.java","line":87},"threadPriority":5,"instant":{"epochSecond":1562919500,"nanoOfSecond":701000000}}`

If I remove the `KeyValuePair` everything works fine as expected.

What's the issue here?

Comment: You will see this message on your console. And in the console the logs are displayed in summary form. If you save in the file instead of the console, it will display the information you have written.

Answer (score 5):

I'm experiencing the same problem. It's somehow related to log4j-2.12.0, in 2.11.2 it is OK.

Comment: Is this answer the question? Kindly remove the comment in here and rewrite just below the original question

Comment: It actually answers the question. Seems like they have a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2652).